# WPF Custom control property set via XAML in own tag

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building a WPF control which will display a component in Display mode, then on a click, will switch to a component in Edit mode.

The two components will be bound such that edit values are reflected on the display component (typically a TextBlock).

My desired syntax for the XAML is as follows.

```
     <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Rating Year">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Controls:EditableControlContainer>
                                <Controls:EditableControlContainer.DisplayControl>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueString}" />
                                </Controls:EditableControlContainer.DisplayControl>
                            </Controls:EditableControlContainer>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
        </ListView.View>
```

The code behind

```
 public partial class EditableControlContainer : UserControl
 {
    private UserControl displayControl;

    public UserControl DisplayControl {
        get { return displayControl; }
        set { displayControl = value; }
    }

    private UserControl editControl;

    public UserControl EditControl {
        get { return editControl; }
        set { editControl = value; }
    }


    public EditableControlContainer() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is that EditableControlContainer.DisplayControl is not recognised or accessible.

I also am uncertain whether I can contain an object or type UserControl (preferably, I'd like to use an interface, although I'm not sure which one).

Can anybody explain or provide a link to a resource which demonstrates how to make properties within the UserControl configurable within the XAML?

I've looked through the forum, but have not been able to find anything which covers this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is this an actual error that causes the code not to compile, or just a squiggly underline indicator in the XAML editor?

Comment: This was causing the code not to compile, but after restarting VS, it's now just showing an error stating that the property does not support TextBlock

Comment: I did some testing also and I had the exact same error you did before restarting VS. I wonder what's wrong with VS and referencing.

Comment: I've had similar issues when I've made a lot of changes to Using statements. Sometimes, VS will just not resolve any of the packages until it's restarted. It just seems to be a quirk in VS, but this is the first time I've encountered it with custom controls configured in XAML.

Comment: Good to know. It can save a lot of headaches to know this.

Comment: As a further consideration, I've changed the types to UIElement from UserControl, and again it's required a restart of VS to clear errors in the XAML. Hopefully this will be addressed in an update to VS at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TextBlock is not a UserControl, if you want to put a TextBlock in there, you need to change the type for display control to TextBlock.

```
private TextBlock displayControl;

public TextBlock DisplayControl {
    get { return displayControl; }
    set { displayControl = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping this could be a more generic approach, but a TextBlock is all I need to support for now.

Comment: You could very probably put UIElement or FrameworkElement as the type, it would make it a bit more generic. Another idea would be to make it a StackPanel, this way you could fit in whatever you want.

Comment: I will experiment with both FrameworkElement and UIElement. I'm reluctant to use a StackPanel as I want the component to resize consistently. I've found stackpanels to be a little finicky in the past regarding resizing.